# GWT - How to put Widget B on Widget A - help

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-ext

I am looking someway to put widgets on each other (each on its layer or something...). Something like the Swing CardLayout but with a transparent background support.

For example

I have

```
Image img=new Image("imageA.png");
HTML h=new HTML("<img src=imageB.png>");
```

How to put "h" on "img" left upper corner?

Any useful comment is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`AbsolutePanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/AbsolutePanel.html). It positions it's children at fixed coordinates so you can make them overlap.

Comment: OK, I'll try the way and report my result

Answer (score 1):

You can either use AbsolutePanel from GWT.
Or you can use CSS set z-index of h higher than img and set absolute position from CSS as you want.

Comment: Could you describe more detailed the "...CSS set z-index " ?

Comment: You can get idea from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369705/css-problem-with-divs/3369864#3369864